# Can Graphics Magick show preview images in terminal?

Tags: bash, syntax, framebuffer, graphicsmagick

I typed in

```
gm display image.jpg
```

and got an error message

```
Unable to open X server.
```

Is there a way to pipe the output of that image file to /dev/fb0 [video framebuffer] to preview the image in Putty over SSH?